# UIScrollView scrollable horizontally even if it has only one page

Tags: swift, xcode, uiscrollview

I have a problem with UIScrollView in my Xcode project. I am using it to show several pictures, but even when it has only one page it still scrolls horizontally. Maybe its something with `setupPhotosInScrollView()` or `scrollViewDidScroll`. I don't know how to fix this issue. It seems ok, but still getting this error. Please help!

Here is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Ad Title
    eTitleLabel.text = "\(eObj[EVENTS_TITLE]!)"

    // Get photos
    let imageFile = eObj[EVENTS_IMAGE1] as? PFFile
    imageFile?.getDataInBackground(block: { (data, error) in
        if error == nil { if let imageData = data {
            self.photosArray.append(UIImage(data: imageData)!)
            self.setupPhotosInScrollView()
            print("PHOTO 1")
    }}})

    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        if self.eObj[EVENTS_IMAGE2] != nil {
            self.pageControl.numberOfPages = 2
            let imageFile = self.eObj[EVENTS_IMAGE2] as? PFFile
            imageFile?.getDataInBackground(block: { (data, error) in
                if error == nil { if let imageData = data {
                    self.photosArray.append(UIImage(data: imageData)!)
                    self.setupPhotosInScrollView()
                    print("PHOTO 2")
            }}})
        }
    // ------------------------------------------------
// MARK: - SETUP PHOTOS IN SCROLLVIEW
// ------------------------------------------------
@objc func setupPhotosInScrollView() {
    var X:CGFloat = 0
    let Y:CGFloat = 0
    let W:CGFloat = view.frame.size.width
    let H:CGFloat = view.frame.size.height
    let G:CGFloat = 0
    var counter = 0

    // Loop to create ImageViews
    for i in 0..<photosArray.count {
        counter = i

        // Create a ImageView
        let aImg = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: X, y: Y, width: W, height: H))
        aImg.tag = i
        aImg.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        aImg.image = photosArray[i]

        // Add ImageViews based on X
        X += W + G
        containerScrollView.addSubview(aImg)

    } // ./ FOR loop

    // Place Buttons into a ScrollView
    containerScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: W * CGFloat(counter+2), height: H)
}


// ------------------------------------------------
// MARK: - CHANGE PAGE CONTROL PAGES ON SCROLL
// ------------------------------------------------
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let pageWidth = containerScrollView.frame.size.width
    let page = Int(floor((containerScrollView.contentOffset.x * 2 + pageWidth) / (pageWidth * 2)))
    pageControl.currentPage = page
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
containerScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: W * CGFloat(counter+2), height: H)
```

With

```
containerScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: W * CGFloat(photosArray.count), height: H)
```

as you set a width for contentSize that's not equal to number of added photos